# Java Swing Button Group setSelected Function

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, buttongroup

I have two radio button here, 'Male' and 'Female'. And i have set 'Male' as String. So how if i want to select the 'Male' Radio Button Automatically by using setSelected function?

Comment: *"So how if i want to select the 'Male' Radio Button Automatically by using setSelected function?"*  You'd do that by **by using setSelected function**.  Or to put that another way, show us what you tried.  And for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

To select a JRadioButton when it is created(Create a selected radio button:

name= new JRadioButton("ButtonName", true);

To select a JRadioButton after it has been created:

name.setSelected(true);